# Best way to find SQL Locks in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, locking

What is the best way to find the SQL locks along wih the user associated with that lock in SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 16):

[`select * from sys.dm_tran_locks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190345.aspx) will list all current locks, granted or pending, along with the requesting session id. [`select * from sys.dm_exec_sessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176013.aspx) will list all current sessions, including the client host and login name. But going this way is very seldom what you want. For a more digestible form, use the [Activity Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175518.aspx) and watch the blocking as reported there.

Comment: In **Activity Monitor**, one can see locks in the _Processes_ tab. One can even filter by username, host, etc., and killing a locking process is as easy as right clicking the process and selecting _Kill Process_.

Answer (score 5):

Run this against the master db:

```
SELECT spid,blocked,program_name,loginame,hostname,lastwaittype,* 
FROM master.dbo.SysProcesses
WHERE blocked <> 0
```