# Is there a way to check locks granted by a transaction

Tags: transactions, sql-server-2008-r2

I am very new to SQL. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have following issues;

**(1)**

A transaction has started but its commit point is not reached.

```
UPDATE Student 
SET subject = 'Technology' 
WHERE subjectCode = 'tech';
```

When this is executing what type of locking is having full table/row??

**(2)**

Is there is a way to get locks held by a transaction?

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12810/5203.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (1):

if the transaction hasn't been blocked by any pre-existing locks, then all rows in the `Student` table with a `subjectCode = 'tech'` will now have a `(X)` (exclusive) lock on them.

On the page and table level, there will be `(IX)` (intent exclusive) locks - signaling that somewhere further down in the "hierarchy" (table -> page -> row) there are exclusive locks in place.

If you're updating more than 5000 rows, then **lock escalation** will have kicked in and SQL Server has replaced the 5000+ individual row-level exclusive locks with a single table-level exclusive lock. That means no one can do anything with that table, basically.

For your question (2) - [see the answers to this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139561/best-way-to-find-sql-locks-in-sql-server-2008).

Comment: Nice explanation for question 1. Thank you.