# External reasons a query runs slowly

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, locking

I would like to know what factors affect the running of a query that do NOT have to do with the query itself. I'm using SQL server, but I guess this might be more universal.

Many times I've executed a query that should take seconds and started to wait like forever (minutes). Then, I pressed stop, and then execute immediately after, and the query would take <1 seconds.

Even worse, I've had good queries running (seemingly) slow, and then we changed to another, less good query, only to have the latter run "fast" and be selected as the best solution. Of course, if we had tested both in "less unfortunate circumstances", the first one would have been better.

What factors play a role in this, and how can I check them? I suppose it has something to do with locks? Will things like this article:
[Best way to find SQL Locks in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139561/best-way-to-find-sql-locks-in-sql-server-2008)
help? Whatever assistance you can provide will be appreciated!

Comment: It also applies to Oracle.  The first time you run your query the database engine compiles the sql and develops an execution plan.  These are both cached for awhile which is why subsequent attempts run faster.

Comment: I highly doubt the creation of one query's plan may take whole minutes.